# How do I redirect to a dashboard now that GIScreenHelper is marked obsolete?

Tags: acumatica

We have a dashboard that is accessed via the Inquiry menu on the Stocked Items page.  Until our most recent minor upgrade on 2019 R2, the following code compiled without issue to allow opening the dashboard relevant to the current Inventory ID.  It still compiles but with a warning that GIScreenHelper is obsolete and will be marked internal in the next upgrade.  Hence my question... how do I redirect to a dashboard if I can't use GIScreenHelper to initialize the graph used in the PXRedirectRequiredException?

```
string screenID = "SS0010DB"; //DashboardID 
PXSiteMapNode sm = GIScreenHelper.GetSiteMapNode(screenID);
PXGraph graph = GIScreenHelper.InstantiateGraph(screenID);
if (graph is LayoutMaint)
{
    LayoutMaint copygraph = graph as LayoutMaint;
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    parameters["InventoryID"] = item.InventoryCD;
    copygraph.Filter.Current.Values = parameters;

    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(sm.Url, copygraph, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, string.Empty);
}
```

I have tried initializing LayoutMaint directly, but I can't figure out what to set to specify which Screen ID to utilize and pass parameters.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have 2 options here:

1. Create the `DashboardMaint` graph instance which is the Dashboards page graph and provide the Name of the Dashboard and invoke the `viewDashboard` action of that graph.
2. Just take the code of the `viewDashboard` action of the DashboardMaint and redirect to your Dashboard directly:

   ```
   [PXButton(ConfirmationType = PXConfirmationType.IfDirty, ConfirmationMessage = "Any unsaved changes will be discarded. Do you want to proceed?")]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "View")]
   public void viewDashboard()
   {
       throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(PXSiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeByScreenID(this.Dashboards.Current.ScreenID).Url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Same, "View Dashboard");
   }
   ```

**UPDATED**

Below is a code example how to open Dashboard with predefined value for Filter.
The example is written for Customer View dashboard.

```
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "CustomerView")]
protected virtual IEnumerable RedirectToCustomerViewDashboard(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    string screenID = "DB000031"; //DashboardID 
    LayoutMaint graph;
    using (new PXScreenIDScope(screenID))
    {
        graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<LayoutMaint>(screenID);
    }
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["CustomerAccountID"] = "ABARTENDE";
    graph.Filter.Current.Values = parameters;
    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(PXSiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeByScreenID(screenID).Url, graph, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, string.Empty);
}
```

The key for the value is Name of the parameter from Dashboard definition

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am trying your suggestion this morning, but I don't see where to give the parameters.  I can go to the dashboard screen directly by URL for the ScreenID as well, it does not accept parameters the same way that LayoutMaint did.  When I give an InventoryID as a parameter while IN the screen it narrows down to my item, but I need to take the user to the dashboard with the InventoryID filled in already. 
 Simply going to the dashboard returns data for all items.  Any guidance on including parameters?

Comment: You pass the page id to PXSiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeByScreenIDUnsecure

Comment: FindSiteMapNodeByScreenIDUnsecure does not appear to be exposed.  Still, I can open the dashboard with a variety of means, but I cannot get it to accept input parameters.  I even tried *throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow, "", parameters);* where parameters is a dictionary pair of "InventoryID" and my InventoryCD value, but it does not populate the InventoryID filter parameter defined for the Dashboard.

Comment: @BrianStevens unfortunately, these `parameters` are for the `string` before them and not for the graph. I am checking if there is any alternative way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the update and code sample.  It works perfectly.